# SonarQube tfsvc plugin - missing blame information for the following files

Tags: tfs, version-control, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I am using SonarQube 5.3 with tfvc plugin 2.1 and TFS 2015 Update 1.

The parameters I have in Sonar.properties are:

```
sonar.scm.enabled=true
sonar.scm.provider=tfvc
sonar.tfvc.username=*xxx*
sonar.tfvc.password.secured=*yyy*
sonar.tfvc.collectionuri=*http://mytfs:8080/tfs/mycollection*
```

When I use the builtin Sonar tasks in TFS vNext builds (it work with XAML builds) the SCM provider doesnt seem to work. I get the following erros in the log:

```
09:04:05.653 INFO  - SCM provider for this project is: tfvc
09:04:05.653 INFO  - 4 files to be analyzed
09:04:05.653 DEBUG - Executing the TFVC annotate command: D:\Builds\Agent1\_work\b33ed2ba\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\.sonartmp\SonarTfsAnnotate1596861656643555411.exe
09:04:05.762 DEBUG - TFS annotating: D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/CalcTest.AddNumbersTest.g.cs
09:04:05.778 INFO  - Unable to TFS annotate the following file which is not in a mapped TFS workspace: D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/CalcTest.AddNumbersTest.g.cs
09:04:05.778 DEBUG - TFS annotating: D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/CalcTest.cs
09:04:05.793 INFO  - Unable to TFS annotate the following file which is not in a mapped TFS workspace: D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/CalcTest.cs
09:04:05.793 DEBUG - TFS annotating: D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
09:04:05.793 INFO  - Unable to TFS annotate the following file which is not in a mapped TFS workspace: D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
09:04:05.793 DEBUG - TFS annotating: D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/Properties/PexAssemblyInfo.cs
09:04:05.793 INFO  - Unable to TFS annotate the following file which is not in a mapped TFS workspace: D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/Properties/PexAssemblyInfo.cs
09:04:05.793 INFO  - 0/4 files analyzed
09:04:05.793 WARN  - Missing blame information for the following files:
09:04:05.793 WARN  -   * D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/Properties/PexAssemblyInfo.cs
09:04:05.793 WARN  -   * D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/CalcTest.AddNumbersTest.g.cs
09:04:05.793 WARN  -   * D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/CalcTest.cs
09:04:05.793 WARN  -   * D:/Builds/Agent1/_work/b33ed2ba/s/WindowsFormsApplication2.Tests01/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
09:04:05.793 WARN  - This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you check if the 4 mentioned files are actually present on your build server in the specified path? A workspace mapping error means that TFVC can't find a file locally.

Comment: Hi Wouter, thanks for your answer. Yes the files are present on the location specified in the log.

Answer (score 1):

I compared the SonarQube.Analysis information for the XAML build and found that I had different accounts for sonar.tfvc.username. The XAML used the TFS build account, when I used that for the vNext build it worked.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer. and your acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/VOTE-SonarQube-SCM-TFS-plugin-2-0-td5035091.html) case and try the workaround there to see whether it is helpful: "*finally I need to do a commit after create the workspace and download the code to make the plugin work. If the commit is made by a third agent the plugin doesn't work either*."

Comment: I recreated my workspaces but I still get the same error, so the workaround does not work. The workaround also talks about a snapshot for the 2.0 version of the plugin, as I am using 2.1 i guess the fixes should be included there?

Comment: I installed a completely new SonarQube server with the plugin but I still get the same error,